# Elgato Facecams are not recognized after reboot until plugged out and in

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-11, camera, windows-11-v22h2

I have several cameras on my PC (2x Elgato FaceCam, 1x Insta360 Link, Logitech C920 and a noname USB camera with focal length adjustment (magnifier).

Motherboard is a [X670 AORUS ELITE AX](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X670-AORUS-ELITE-AX-rev-10) with an additional PCIe x4 to USB 3.2 Gen2 card 7-port PCI Express expansion card.

Currently, the only other things connected besides the cameras mentioned are a keyboard, a mouse, a DJI Mic receiver and a Elgato StreamDeck XL.

Some of the cameras are connected with a 2m or 3m extension cord (specified for USB 3.2 Gen 2). They work fine at full frame rate (with no dropouts or other issues). The Logitech C920 is connected to a active 15m extension with a switch behind it, which also supplies the extension cable with power.

I'm using Windows 11 Pro, 22H2 build 22621.1928 with all currently available updates installed.

Now, after turning the PC off and on again (or rebooting), sometimes either one or the other Elgato FaceCam is not available. The other three cameras and all other connected devices do not cause any problems. Sometimes everything goes fine 10 times and then on the 11th time one or two cameras are missing again.

If I simply swap the USB port of the missing camera on the PC after booting Windows, the camera is usually recognized. If everything stays like this and I switch off the PC and switch it on again (or reboot the PC), the respective camera is sometimes not available again.

I only use the USB 3.2 Gen 2 ports on both the mainboard and the expansion card for the two problematic cameras mentioned. It makes no difference whether the camera was plugged into the mainboard directly or on the expansion card. Of course, I've also tried around with the USB 3.2 Gen 1 ports.

I have installed the latest chipset driver for the motherboard and am using the driver automatically installed by Windows for the expansion card.

Does anyone have any idea how this is happening and what else I can do about it? Are there any log files on this? Is it possible to trigger the process that happens after a USB device is unplugged (task scheduling?).

Comment: The extension cables are likely to blame. Try connecting them to a externally powered USB 3.2 Gen 2 hub

Comment: If all the devices are powered via USB, it might be that the PSU has weakened and cannot support all of them. You could test by, when it happens, unplugging one device and reboot again.

Comment: Sadly I have no usb hub with this specification. The other problem is, the cameras are all mounted and need to be, where they are. It does not help, if a hub may solve the problem, because I'll need a hub for every single camera. My PSU has 500 watts. The PC has a Nvidia RTX3060 12GB graphics card and a 8x 3,8 GHz AMD RYZEN 7-7700 - shouldn't this be enough? I want to know, if there is a software to analyze the problem.